# Get the chosen shipping method cost in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, the following won't return any output and I don't know why.

Can this not be multiplied like this?

```
$price = (wc_price($selectedShipping->cost)*1.15);
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `wc_price($selectedShipping->cost)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing like this:

```
$temp = ($selectedShipping->cost) * 1.15;
$price = wc_price($temp);
```